# How to embed jars to make them usable in Xamarin cross-platform App

Tags: android, jar, cross-platform, xamarin

I am trying to port my Android Application, developed with Google Android ADT, in Xamarin to make it cross-platform and runnable on iOS devices.

I am ready to translate the needed code from Java to C# but I don't know the best way to manage external libraries.

I am using 3 jars in my App:

- android-support-v4.jar
- mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar
- YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar

I tried to embed them following these instructions:
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29

but I'm getting some compilation errors. Here's one of them:

```
'Com.Mysql.Jdbc.Util' in '[..]\AndroidHelloWorld\JavaBindingLibrary\obj\Release\generated\src\Com.Mysql.Jdbc.Util.cs'
is in conflict with 
'Com.Mysql.Jdbc.Util' in '[..]\AndroidHelloWorld\JavaBindingLibrary\obj\Release\generated\src\Com.Mysql.Jdbc.Util.BaseBugReport.cs'
```

I don't know if it's worth going on trying to fix the errors or it's better to use native libraries for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'll have separate projects for each platform, I would just use the appropriate jars, as there can be differences in the way Youtube works, for example, that would make the android jar unusable in an iOS project.
But about the errors you encountered, it's worth reading [this link](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29) thoroughly.

Comment: Yes I think it's better to use native libraries rather than try to integrate jars.

Comment: @Andreaoid Even though I'm using native libraries for each platform, this has been by far the hardest part of developing a monodroid app.
Also remeber to check out the Xamarin forums for more help.

Comment: @VitorMBarbosa I've supposed it will be tough. I just started to develop in Xamarim but I'm already figuring out what will be the hardest problems to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use any of your Android specific code or libraries on iOS.

You have two basic options for cross platform development, to create a Xamarin Forms project or create a iOS, Android and Shared project.

If you decide to go with Xamarin Forms you will need to:
* Extract your platform independent code into a shared PCL project
* Redevelop your front end in Xamarin Forms

If you decide to go with separate projects you will need to:
* Extract your platform independent code into a shared PCL project
* Develop an iOS front end project